# Duplicate Directory with SSH

Tags: ssh, directory

How can i duplicate a directory on my server via ssh?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cp -r directory_name destination
```

> ```
>   -R, -r, --recursive
>           copy directories recursively
> ```

... or maybe you want to exchange folders between hosts. Than you should use rsync

```
rsync -vaz --rsh="ssh -l username" ~/bk targetHost:~/test
```

Comment: you mean rsync -vaz ~/bk username@targetHost:~/test

Answer (score 3):

tar also would be a candidate for this job:

```
tar cf - . | ssh user@host 'cd /$destination && tar xBf -'
```

Comment: While a little more complicated, tar is awesome for when you need the files to *exactly* match.  I tend to use this for cloning filesystems or uncompressed backups.

Comment: using tar over ssh like that is also a number of times faster than scp or rsync when dealing with a lot of tiny files.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with either rsync or scp, both of which go over ssh.

```
scp -rp directory remotehost:/path/to/directory

rsync -azv -e ssh directory/ remotehost:/path/to/directory
```

Comment: ... and I forgot about scp.